# Display Picker.Item based on data structure - React-Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Suppose I have a data structure like the following:

```
pickerOptions = {
  option1:['i1','i2','i3'],
  option2:['i1','i2','i3'],
  option3:['i1','i2','i3']
}
```

How can I display the items in the array based on the key I select.
Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

you can use flatlist to show your data and by using JS (filter function), you may filter specific row. Try this code

```
import React from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, View, FlatList, StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';


const pickerOptions = [
  {key:'1',value1:'i1',value2:'i2',value3:'i3'},
{key:'2',value1:'i1',value2:'i2',value3:'i3'},
  {key:'3',value1:'i1',value2:'i2',value3:'i3'},
]


function Item({ title }) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.item}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={pickerOptions}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <View style={{flexDirection:"row", paddingTop:20}}> 
              <Text style={{paddingLeft:10}}>{item.value1} </Text>
              <Text style={{paddingLeft:10}}>{item.value2} </Text>
              <Text style={{paddingLeft:10}}>{item.value3} </Text>
        </View>}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
  },
  item: {
    backgroundColor: '#f9c2ff',
    padding: 20,
    marginVertical: 8,
    marginHorizontal: 16,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 32,
  },
});
```

Also check on expo, here is the link

https://snack.expo.io/?session_id=snack-session-u3SFTaX40&preview=true&platform=web&iframeId=u7m30esbbi&supportedPlatforms=ios,android,web&name=flatlist-simple&description=Example%20usage&waitForData=true